# iOS: programmatically draw a rectangle on top of a button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I need to draw a rectangle on top of a UIButton. Assume that there's a UIButton called hideMe, and this button has 100x50 size. I want to place a 100x10 rectangle on top of this button every time a user receives a message. If the user receives five messages, then the button will be completely covered by the rectangles. How do I do this?

Comment: You could draw the rectangle _in_ the button as its background image. If you really want to _cover_ the button, just put an image view in front of it and draw your rectangle image and display it.

Comment: What if I need to draw indefinite number of such rectangles to cover the button? The button already has a background image, so using a background image wouldn't work unless there's a way to place background images in front of the already-existing one.

Comment: This question is more specific and has screenshots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826244/modifying-a-table-cell. Each table cell is a button.

Comment: But you can draw in code, at any time. So you could modify the background image to be the current image plus a rectangle covering part of it. Or draw the rectangle into the image view, I don't care which you do. Do you not know how to draw images in code? It is very easy, and is an important part of iOS programming. Rectangle drawing is as simple as you can get.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your help! Would it be possible to open a chat if I wanted to ask you some more detailed questions?

Answer (score 1):

```
CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
topBorder.borderWidth = 2;
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 15, <tempButton>.frame.size.width,  <tempButton>.frame.size.height-30);
[<tempButton>.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
```

The above  code helps you to draw the rectangle.You can increase the layer frames to cover full.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

here we are drawing our own border rect and sub viewing it to our button

```
-(UIView*)borderRectWithYvalue:(CGFloat)yValue
{
    UIView * rect = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,yValue, 100, 10)];
    rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    rect.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor redColor]);
    rect.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    return rect;
}
```

and call this method when and where you want to add border to your button with your custom `y` value

for ex

`[yourButton addSubview:[self borderRectWithYvalue:10.0]];`